# GPS in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gps, nexus

I am trying to implement a GPS into Android Studio. The code I wrote has no errors, but once I try to upload it on the device, which is Nexus 5X API 27, the application stops and it does not show me the current location (which is what the code is supposed to do). I made the app by implementing the Google Maps into my project and already got the key permission requested. It could be that the code I am trying to run is a little outdated for the app version (which is 2020.3.1 Patch 3) but I still got no clue what I should change.
This is my MapsActivity.java code:

```
package mylocation.example.myllocation;

//import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import mylocation.example.myllocation.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;

    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private final long MIN_TIME = 1000; // 1 second
    private final long MIN_DIST = 5; // 5 Meters

    private LatLng latLng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

// Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(“Marker in Sydney”));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                try {
                    latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Position"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                }
                catch (SecurityException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DIST, locationListener);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with this please? :)

Comment: The android version of the application and the version of the phone may not match. You could try updating the libraries. If these do not work and nothing is returned in the log section, you can run the Analyze section in Android Studio to see in more detail what could cause the error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
"The app stops" means that it crashes, or simply keeps running without returning the location? Have you tried to place a log line in order to verify if the location is obtained? In a test with a real device the first FIX could be obtained after some time, specially if you make tests in a closed space like at your desk: better to make the first tests using a emulator, that obtains the location in a couple of seconds.